# n digit number made up of 1s and 2s. Divisibility by $2^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If an n-digit number is made up of $1$s and $2s$ (for $n\geq2$), show that there is at least one such number that is divisible by $2^n$. Moreover, is there a general way to represent such a number that is divisible by $2^n$?

Although the solution can be solved with induction, I am trying to find if there is a general way to represent the n digit number that is divisible by $2^n$, or if some sort of algorithm could be generated whereby the sequence of $1$s and $2$s in the number is always divisible by $2^n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start trying to find values for $n=2,3,4$. You can find easily $12,112,2112$. Checking OEIS with these values you find the sequence [A053312](https://oeis.org/A053312) and the formula for an $n$-digit number ($n \ge 1$) divisible by $2^n$:

$$a(n) = a(n-1)+10^{n-1}\left[2-\left(\frac{a(n-1)}{2^{n-1}} \mod 2\right)\right]$$

with $a(1)=2$.

If $a(n-1)$ is divisible by $2^n$ then the formula becomes:

$$a(n) = a(n-1) + 10^{n-1} \cdot 2 = 2^n\cdot k + 2^n \cdot 5^{n-1}=2^n(k+5^{n-1})$$

If $a(n-1)$ is not divisible by $2^n$ then the formula becomes:

$$a(n) = a(n-1)+10^{n-1} = 2^{n-1}(2k+1)+2^{n-1}5^{n-1}=2^{n-1}(2k+1+5^{n-1})=2^n\cdot m$$